# Convert file string data to json python

Tags: python, json

I've file where data is in below string format.

```
Name      : XYZ
Address   : London
Occupation : Teacher 
Age       : 34

Name      : ABC
Address   : New York
Occupation : Business 
Age       : 39
```

I want to convert data to json as show in below format:

```
   {
    Name      : XYZ
    Address   : London
    Occupation : Teacher 
    Age       : 34
   },

   {
    Name      : ABC
    Address   : New York
    Occupation : Business 
    Age       : 39
   }
```

I've tried below so far:

```
def convert() :
    f = open("file.txt", "r")
    content = f.read()
    splitcontent = content.splitlines()
    data = json.dumps(splitcontent, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
    print(data)

O/P: [Name      : XYZ,        Address   : London, Occupation : Teacher,  Age       : 34, Name      : ABC, Address   : New York, Occupation : Business, Age       : 39]
```

Comment: List comp which generate list of dicts: `[dict((i.strip() for i in l.split(':')) for l in s.splitlines()) for s in file_data.split('\n\n')]`. To print it nice use `json.dumps()` with `indent` argument: `print(json.dumps([dict((i.strip() for i in l.split(':')) for l in s.splitlines()) for s in file_data.split('\n\n')], indent=4))`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght:Facing this error:
 ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #11 has length 1; 2 is required

Comment: It means that format of your file is different form example you provided in question. This error means that one of line doesn't contain `':'` so `str.split()` returns list with single element.

Answer (score 1):

```
def convert(file_name):
    objects = []
    with open(file_name) as f:
        d = {}
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith("Age"):
                key, value = line.split(":")
                d[key.strip()] = value.strip()
                objects.append(d)
                d = {}
            else:
                try:
                    key, value = line.split(":")
                    d[key.strip()] = value.strip()
                except ValueError as v:
                    pass

    return objects
print(convert("infile.txt"))
```

Comment: this worked fine with few modifications. Thanks. In dictionary, 1 key has multi line value. While fetching that key, only single line value is being fetched. Is there any way by which I can fetch all the lines ?

Comment: if there is only one such key, then you can use couple of if conditions to make sure you are fetching value.